# Calculating the lateral area of a cone

Tags: geometry

On my book, it says

> ...thinking of the lateral surface as swept out by revolving a generator (i.e. slant height) about the axis: the lateral area equals the length of this generator multiplied by the distance traveled by its midpoint, $ s*2pi*(\frac{1}{2}r) = pi*r*s $ ...

However, I can't understand why midpoint is involved. I looked up two proofs online ([one of them](http://www.mathopenref.com/coneareaderivation.html)), but both of them are different from my book's proof, and actually they seem more reasonable to me. Is my book wrong?

Update: my question is that how do you get the left hand side of the equation $ s*2pi*(\frac{1}{2}r) = pi*r*s $. Namely, why do you use $ \frac{1}{2}r $ and what's the point of using midpoint?

Comment: You can see on net for Moment of Inertia i think itll help . The midpoint is taken as $dx$ for total area.And then integrated for total area.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar Although I have learned basic calculus, this book is a precalculus book, so I think there shouldn't be calculus involved.

Comment: But the title says lateral area of cone and revolving generator is more like a cylinder.

Comment: And the rolling generator can be made up of two cones and at midpoint  the generator is like a cylindrical tyre.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar It is the lateral area. The book says generator probably because it's old (1987). And that's why I also noted that generator means slant height.

Comment: I know other way of doing this . Surface Area is given by circumference multiplied by distance travelled .$A=c.d$ so $A=πr.s$

Comment: @ArchisWelankar Sorry, but I can't understand your point. Also, I'm just curious about why the book uses midpoint. Other methods are not my concerns. sorry :(

Comment: Note Midpoint of generator is centre of gravity for the generator . Hence the midpoint is taken into consideration . Hope this helps you.

Comment: Pick two points equidistant from the midpoint.  Does the total length of the two circles they trace out equal twice the length of the circle the midpoint traces out?  This is why the midpoint is the right choice: individual points trace out more or less length, but they come in pairs which cancel the discrepancies.

Comment: @EricTowers But why the area formula uses the radius at the midpoint? How do you know that the midpoint is the right answer? Without knowing the lateral area, why do you use the radius at the midpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm reading the same book and, no surprise, had the same question. I've given it some thought and here's my best guess:

Think about what's happening when we revolve the generator (or slant length, *s*) around the axis. At the very top of the cone sits a single point, which doesn't move at all. At the very bottom of the cone (on its edge, which is one of the endpoints of the generator) sits a point which rotates around the entire base of the cone. The distance traveled by this point is 2*pi*r.

Now, how far does the *average* point on the generator travel on its trip around the axis? Intuition suggests it's the average of the distance traveled by each endpoint. That equals (0 + 2*pi*r)/2, which equals (1/2)(2*pi*r).

So, the points composing the generator move an average distance of pi(r) as they "sweep out" the lateral area of the cone. This implies that the lateral area is equal to the length of the generator multiplied by pi(r), which as shown above is the distance traveled by the generator's midpoint.

One thing to note: the author says that "the lateral area equals the length of this generator multiplied by the distance traveled by its midpoint." He then asserts (without proof) that the midpoint of the generator lies at the point on the cone where the cross-sectional radius is equal to 1/2 the radius of the cone's base. See if you can convince yourself if this assertion is justified.

Comment: Actually I figured this out shortly after I posted this question...but it's been a long time and I forgot what's my thoughts back then. Thanks anyway...

Comment: Also for the assertion. Can you use congruent triangles? :)

Comment: @shidangai exactly, my friend!

Answer (score -1):

See cone is formed by joining the end of the sector of a circle.

Let us take a circle of radius small r and the angle between the two radius is theta(this is the sector) so the area of the sector is theta divided by 360 degrees multiplied by pi*r^2

Next we should eliminate the theta, for that I am taking the circle at the base of the cone of radius r'(this circle is formed by joining the ends of the sector). Now the circumference of the circle at the base of the cone is (2*pi*r')

This circumference will be equal to that sector's circumference that is theta/360 multiplied by (2*pi*r)

Now equate,

2*pi*r' = theta/360 multiplied by (2*pi*r)

Now we can get theta angle to be 360*r' divided by r .

Now substitute the theta value in the first equation

It will be 360*r'/r divided by 360 multiplied by pi*r^2
This will be equal to pi*r*r'

Here r is equal to the slant height (s) that implies pi*s*r'

Hence proved

Comment: This is a valid proof. But it doesn't explain the left hand side of the equation in the book (and that's mainly my problem).

Comment: Proof is correct know....

Comment: The problem is not about the proof. It's about why midpoint is involved.